# Cannot login/logout with Devise, because "uninitialized constant Users::SessionsController"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I have following setup in **routes.rb**:

```
  devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout" },
                     controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "authentications", registrations: "users/registrations", :sessions => "users/sessions" }
  devise_scope :user do
    ... some other routes ...
  end
```

When I try to sign up, log in or log out, I always get a similar error message like this:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Users::SessionsController
```

In controllers, I have a folder called **users** and in this folder is **registrations_controller.rb** with following content:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
  end

  def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth]
      @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
      @user.valid?
    end
  end
end
```

How to get rid of that error message?

Thank you.

Comment: and you dont have users/sessions_controller?

Comment: your error message says you haven't right defined `Users::SessionsController`, plz check it.

Comment: where did you define the **Users::SessionsController**?

Comment: Thank you guys, I noticed that I have in routes this: **:sessions => "users/sessions"** -- I removed that and now it seems to be working.